# Funny UIScrollView when using presentViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, zooming

**Summary:**
I have a UIScrollView with zoomable content. If the content is NOT zoomed and I presentViewController, everything is fine when I dismiss that ViewController. But, if I have zoomed the content and then presentViewController, the content and the UIScrollView are all wacky when I dismiss the ViewController. Any help is welcome, this is an awful bug... Thank you!

**Test Project:**
A simple test can be found here...

http://twostatesaway.com/ModalWithScrollViewTEST.zip

or here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0pG5vRVzBTzdkVzdEtkdmVjdDA/edit?usp=sharing

**Screen Shots:**

Screen 1: Everything fine. I can show the modal a million times and the content will work as expected after dismissing the modal

Screen 2: Zoom in on content.

Screen 3: When I click the button to presentViewController, the content shifts to the right as the ViewController (in black) is coming up.

Screen 4: Modal is on screen.

Screen 5: When I dismiss the ViewConroller, the content is funny, the bright green view seems to go back to normal, but the button stays in its zoom position, still shifted to the right.

Screen 6: Another funny things is that now I can zoom out more than before. The min zoom is set at 1.0, but now it seems like that is not working.

[image]

Comment: I think Your button in not inside the yellow view.

Comment: I think you didn't download the test project.

Comment: Google Drive & all other sharing sites are blocked in my office.

Comment: http://twostatesaway.com/ModalWithScrollViewTEST.zip

Comment: Why are you using xib in storyboard project?

Comment: This is just a test project. I'm not too concerned with the best practices... Has no one ever seen this before? And are you all able to see the problem? or is it just me?

Comment: I'm filing a bug for this now but wondering if anyone else has taken a shot at this... it seems very wrong.

Comment: Come on peeps, can anyone solve this. I have content that I would like to stay zoomed in after making a selection in a ModalViewController. Is no one else having/seeing this as a major problem? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted work around here is to capture the zoom and contentOffset when the modal is coming up, and then set the properties when view is appearing again...

```
//// Capture values
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    zoomedScale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;
    contentOffsetTemp = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
}

//// This prevents the content from getting messed up (thanks user1673099)
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
}

//// Then reassign them values
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomedScale;
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = contentOffsetTemp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

1) Remove the code from `- (IBAction)openModal:(id)sender`  & make it blank.

2) In story board make the secondViewController class as `ModalViewController` as below.

[image]

3) Drag the line from button to second view & use segue as modal as shown below.

[image]

**Updated answer**

1) clear the `viewDidLoad` method.

2) Write following code in `ViewWillAppear method.`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    //self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 200);
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
}
```

Comment: **Please Let me now if you have any problem.**

Comment: Is this useful to you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: @user273312,**I got the solution Just check my updated answer.**

Comment: Nope, your answer helps, but it just resets everything, I want it to remain zoomed in... I appreciate your help. I can't believe this is so buggy. its simple code. I wonder if apple doesn't test this kind of stuff or what, it seems like a common setup.